# Tell the user that you're passing a value in the map callback

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm developing a package with a .d.ts file that needs for the user to pass a map with `MessageMenuOption` and if the map value is a function I want to tell the user that I'm passing an argument `btn` and its type is `MessageComponent`.

```js
declare class Page {
    constructor(name: string, content: MessageEmbed, buttons: Map<MessageMenuOption, string | Function>, index: number)
    name: string
    content: MessageEmbed
    buttons: Map<MessageMenuOption, string | Function /* Hey if you specified a function as the map value I'm passing btn : MessageComponent */>
}
```

Comment: By "I'm passing an argument btn" you mean that btn with type `MessageComponent` will be passed as an argument to function?

Comment: Yes, I want to tell the user that I'm passing an argument to his function

Comment: You can create an inline arrow function `| (component: MessageComponent) => any`